# Java Collectors.groupingBy cant find error

Tags: java, java-stream, collect

The compiler gives me a Non-static method error here, I already know that does not mean that it has to be the problem but i really can not find anything else, especially since I have the same method in a different class just for pass plays an everything works.

```
public Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Double>> setup(ArrayList<RunPlay> play){
Map<Integer, Map<Integer,Double>> map =
         plays.stream()
                    .collect(
                            Collectors.groupingBy(RunPlay::getYardline, Collectors.groupingBy(RunPlay::getDown, Collectors.averagingDouble(PassPlay::getPoints)))
                    );
    return map;
```

here is the RunPlay class:

```
public class RunPlay {

private int yardline;
private int down;
private int togo;
private int gained;
private int td;

public RunPlay(int yardline, int down, int togo, int gained, int td){

    this.down=down;
    this.gained=gained;
    this.td=td;
    this.togo=togo;
    this.yardline=yardline;

}

public double getPoints(){
    double result=0;
    result+=((getGained()*0.1)+(td*6));
    return result;
}

public int getYardline() {
    return yardline;
}

public int getGained() { return gained; }

public int getDown() { return down; }

public int getTd() {
    return td;
}

public int getTogo() {
    return togo;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elements of your `stream` pipeline are `RunPlay` instances. So when you call `RunPlay::getYardline` the relevant method is called on that passed in object which is in your case a `RunPlay` instance. But how can you call `PassPlay::getPoints`, which is not possible in this context using a method reference. So if you need to do that you have to use a lambda expression like so assuming the method is an instance method,

```
Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Double>> map = plays.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(RunPlay::getYardline, Collectors.groupingBy(RunPlay::getDown,
        Collectors.averagingDouble(ignored -> new PassPlay().getPoints()))));
```

However you can use the same method reference which you used above in this context, which is legal.

```
Function<PassPlay, Double> toDoubleFn = PassPlay::getPoints;
```

So the `getPoints` method will be called on the passed in instance.